# pagination error in taxonomy: Warning: Division by zero

Tags: pagination, errors

I'm trying to list a taxonomy in alphabetical order. I've found west code to do it but it gives throws an error: Warning: Division by zero

functions.php

```
if( !function_exists('a_z_pagination') ){
function a_z_pagination() {
$order = isset( $_REQUEST['sortby'] ) ?  trim($_REQUEST['sortby']) : null;
$sort_array = array(
'A' =>  __('A','framework'),
'B' =>  __('B','framework'),
'C' =>  __('C','framework'),
'D' =>  __('D','framework'),
'E' =>  __('E','framework'),
'F' =>  __('F','framework'),
'G' =>  __('G','framework'),
'H' =>  __('H','framework'),
'I'    =>   __('I','framework'),
'J'    =>   __('J','framework'),
'K' =>  __('K','framework'),
'L' =>  __('L','framework'),
'M' =>  __('M','framework'),
'N' =>  __('N','framework'),
'O' =>  __('O','framework'),
'P' =>  __('P','framework'),
'Q' =>  __('Q','framework'),
'R' =>  __('R','framework'),
'S' =>  __('S','framework'),
'T' =>  __('T','framework'),
'U' =>  __('U','framework'),
'V' =>  __('V','framework'),
'W' =>  __('W','framework'),
'X' =>  __('X','framework'),
'Y' =>  __('Y','framework'),
'Z' =>  __('Z','framework')
);
$block = '';
$block .= '<div class="paginator lighter"><ul>';
foreach ( $sort_array as $key=>$value ){
$active = ( $order == $key ) ? 'selected' : null;
$block .= '<li><a class="'.$active.'"  href="'.get_permalink().'?sortby='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a></li>';     
}
$block .= '</ul></div>';
print $block; 
}
add_action('a_z_pagination', 'a_z_pagination');
}
```

page Error in line: 'total'   => ceil($total_terms / $per_page )

```
<?php do_action('a_z_pagination'); // A Z PAGINATION IS HERE!  ?>

<div class="content">
<?php
$per_page = '1';
$sortby = isset($_GET['sortby']) ? $_GET['sortby'] : null;
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
// number of tags to show per-page
$per_page = $number_of_performers ;
$offset = ( $page -1 ) * $per_page;
$args = array( 'orderby' => $orderby,  'number' => $per_page,  
    'offset' => $offset,
    'exclude'       => array(), 
    'exclude_tree'  => array(), 
    'include'       => array(),
    'fields'        => 'all', 
    'hierarchical'  => true, 
    'child_of'      => 0, 
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'pad_counts'    => false,
    //'terms'     =>  $term->slug,
    'cache_domain'  => 'core' );
$taxonomy = 'autor';
$count_performers = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $offset );
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
$total_terms = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $offset );
?>
<?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tag) : ?>
<?php 
$flag = 0; 
if( $sortby == substr( $tag->name, 0, 1 ) || $sortby=='' ) {    $flag = 1;} 
if ($flag=='1'){ // BELOW IS THE LAST POST IMAGE FROM TAX
?>
<div class="thumbs">

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($tag->slug, 'autor'); ?>" title="<?php echo $tag->name; ?>">  

<?php $args = 
 array ('showposts' => 1,'orderby' => 'rand','order' => 'DESC','tax_query' => array(
      array('taxonomy' => 'autor','field'    => 'term_id','terms'    => $tag->term_id,),
   ),
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) { while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) { $new_query->the_post();  $post_id = get_the_ID();
get_template_part( 'templates/image', get_post_format() ); } 
} else {
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

</a>

<p><?php echo $tag->name; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $tag->count;  _e('libros', 'framework'); ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
echo '<div class="paginator lighter">'; // NUMERIC PAGINATION IS HERE!
   $page_next = 'NEXT PAGE'; $page_prev = 'PREVIOUS PAGE';
   $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
   if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { $ranger = $mid_size; } else { $ranger = '3'; }
   echo paginate_links( 
   array(
       'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
       'format'  => '/page/%#%',
        'current'       => max( 1, $paged ),
        'prev_text'     => $page_prev,
        'next_text'     => $page_next,
        'show_all'      => false,
        'mid_size' => $ranger,
        'before_page_number' => '',
        'type' => 'list',
          'after_page_number' => '',
        'total'   => ceil($total_terms / $per_page )  // Error:  Warning: Division by zero
    ) 
 );
echo '</div>';
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: where do you set `$number_of_performers`?

Comment: Clearly either `$total_terms` or `$per_page` is zero, can you make your code more readable by indenting correctly, removing unnecessary closing an open tags, and making sure there is 1 thing per line rather than multiple things per line? Your editor should automatically do a lot of this for you as you write code, consider a better editor such as Atom, Sublime Text, or PHPStorm, the first 2 of which can be used for free

Answer (score 1):

`$per_page` is `$number_of_performers`, which must be an incorrect value.

PS: Also you can reduce your `$sort_array` defines with:

```
$sort_array = array();
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
foreach ($alphas as $lttr)
   $sort_array[$lttr] = __($lttr,'framework');
```

---

**UPDATE**

furthering @tom-j-nowell point of `$total_terms` being the problem - your codes [`wp_count_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_terms)'s second argument is supposed to be [an array or a string query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), not an integer like `$offset` is.

While troubleshooting, it may benefit to see the math and variable values so you can get a better idea what is the problem. Above your `.paginator.lighter` echo, I'd add:

```
echo "<pre>
total_terms = {$total_terms}\n
per_page = {$per_page}\n
---
total = ".($total_terms/$per_page)."</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have solved the error by eliminating the lines:

Comment: I have solved the error by eliminating the lines: `$per_page = $number_of_performers ; $count_performers = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $offset );`  Now I have another problem. $ per_page = '3'; On page 1 only shows one result and in the rest 3.